# preg_match returns weird result

Tags: php, regex, preg-match-all

I need to extract text in curly braces but only if the first word within them is a "allowed" word.
for example the following text:

```
awesome text,
a new line {find this braces},
{find some more} in the next line.
Please {dont find} this ones.
```

in this simple example "find" stands for a allowed word

my attemp:

```
$pattern        = '!{find(.*)}!is';
$matches        = array();
preg_match_all( $pattern, $text, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER );
```

returns a weird result (print_r):

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => {find this braces},
    {find some more} in the next line.
    Please {dont find}
            [1] =>  this braces},
    {find some more} in the next line.
    Please {dont find
        )

)
```

while working fine without the "find" in the pattern (but then the one with "dont" is found, too.

What may be the cause for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`.*` would match greedily i.e as much as possible.Use `.*?` to match lazily i.e as less as possible

So your regex would be

```
!{find(.*?)}!is
```

Alternatively you can use `[^{}]` instead of `.*?`..In that case you don't need to use singleline mode

```
!{find([^{}]*)}!i
```

Comment: you are faster than me :p

Comment: @nut I guess I was the first one to see this question..;)